# How to convert rects to contour

Tags: python, opencv

With OpenCV we can generate a rect `(list)` from a contour

```
[x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
```

Where `x` and `y` are the coordinate of a point and `w` and `h` are the respective width and height.

Is there a method to convert these rects back to contours?

Answer (score 0):

A contour is simply a list of points. So just convert the `x, y, w, h` values into points, store it in a list, and that's your contour.

So your points will be `(x, y), (x+w, y), (x, y+h), (x+w), (y+h)` and your contour will be `[(x, y), (x+w, y), (x, y+h), (x+w), (y+h)]`

**Clarification:**

I should've been more detailed. Use this code to convert your points into a contour.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
    
x = 10
y = 20
width = 50
height = 60

img = np.zeros((100,100,1), np.uint8)

p1 = np.matrix([[x, y]])
p2 = np.matrix([[x + width, y]])
p3 = np.matrix([[x, y + height]])
p4 = np.matrix([[x + width, y + height]])

contour = list(np.array([[p1, p2, p3, p4]]))

cv2.drawContours(img, contour, -1, 255)

cv2.imshow("image", img)
if cv2.waitKey() == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I am getting a ValueError of `setting an array element with a sequence`. Should we be appending 5 tuples into the list?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some clarification and code that should get you going in the right direction